# How to Add Affix to Bootstrap Fixed Bottom Navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all, please be inform that I already know, we can add `affix` utility to all kind of regular `navbar` in Bootstrap, In my case ,however, I need to add the affix to a specifically `navbar-fixed-bottom` Navbar.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<div class="container" style="height:3000px;"></div>
```

The reson that I would like to do this is presenting the navbar at the bottom of `viewport` on page loading and on scroll down affix it to the top.

Can you please let me know if this is doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add CSS to handle the navbar when `affix` is applied. In your case, that would be changing the navbar `top:0;` so that it no longer is fixed to the botttom.

```
.affix.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/jYikJAul9j

Comment: Thanks a lot Zim but is there any way we can add animation to it? I mean right now it looks like the navbar is jumping to the top! is there any way we can have smooth scroll there?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.. you need the add the CSS for it.  Read here to learn about the affix classes http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix-usage